"Need Help Reducing 22GB DAE File to 50MB in Blender"
I have a DAE file that is around 22GB, including textures, and contains 14 large buildings. I've already split the file into separate buildings, with each building ranging from 200MB to 1.5GB in size. Using various methods, such as removing unnecessary data, decimating objects, replacing textures with solid colors, and merging by distance, I've managed to reduce the size of each building to between 2.5MB and 66MB. However, I'm still unable to reduce the overall file size below 200MB. Can anyone suggest additional techniques to reduce the Blender file size to 50MB?

When saving the file, make sure to open the "Numbers Panel" in the File View either by pressing N or by clicking on the gear icon ⚙, then enable the "Compress" option.

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

oh wait.. so the N-panel was the Numbers Panel all along? always wondered what N stood for because I could not find it in the documentation.

@HarryMcKenzie It's weird because there's no numbers, but I always called it the Numbers Panel and I'm not the only one. I think I've heard it first on the Blenderguru's donut tutorial (the one in 2.79 version).

Interesting. I always thought it was called N-Panel because you can access it with keyboard shortcut N :p

@HarryMcKenzie It's possible the "Numbers" is just an ad-hoc rationalization of the keyboard shortcut. The panel is called "context" in bindings, and was called "properties" in 2.79, I don't have an older version to check if it maybe was called something else earlier.

Well, if you open the N panel in the viewport with the Items tab, it shows a lot of numbers: in Object Mode all the transformation values and the dimensions of an object. And in Edit Mode it also shows vertices data and edges data etc., so maybe that's why people call it the "Numbers Panel".
